# Compare pairs of CSV files and colour the cells in the second file which don't match

Tags: perl, csv

I have 22 CSV files which have multiple columns and rows. Half of them are in folder `A` and the rest are in folder `B`.

I want to compare each file in folder `A` with the file with the same name in folder `B`. If any cell values are different then those cells of the file in folder `B` should be highlighted in yellow.

Can someone please let me know whether this can be done using a Perl script? I am very new to Perl; can someone please help me to create a Perl script?

Comment: It can be done with a perl script. You probably want to start with reading up on hashes, and how they work - they're quite good for finding duplicates/unique items.

Comment: Sure, we can help. But by the definition of the help: _to make it possible or easier for someone to do something, by doing **part** of the work yourself or by providing advice, support, etc.:_ - you need to start - and show us where you stuck.

Comment: There's no way to *colour* fields in a CSV file. It is just a string of characters without any format information at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to open your CSV files; [`<>` or `readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) to read lines of text from the file; [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to split the lines into fields; and [`cmp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) to compare whether two field values are equal.

Comment: thanks a lot for teh assistance. i will use your method.